# How to fix my program so that it returns my actual defined function when called, instead of <function name at 0x3424243>?

Tags: python

Why does my program return `"function name at 0x3424243"` whenever I call my defined function?
To let you know that 3424243 isn't the actual number, but either way it shows a very random number, whenever I call my defined function.

My code:

```
print("WELCOME!")
name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
print("\nHello " + name + "!")

def name():
    print(name)

print("\nGoodbye", name)
```

How can I fix this so that it says goodbye to the name I typed in. The code above generates      "Goodbye, function name at 0x3424243>"

Answer (score 3):

**Don't use the same name for the input variable and the function.**

---

First:

```
name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
```

Will run and `name` will point to the input string.

When:

```
def name():
```

Is evaluated `name` will start pointing to the function instead of the input string.

---

Modify your code like this:

```
print("WELCOME!")
name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
print("\nHello " + name + "!")

def fn():          # Changed the name of the function to avoid the clash.
    return name    # Return the name.

print("\nGoodbye", fn())
```

Output:

```
WELCOME!

What is your name? 
Hello Dipen!

Goodbye Dipen
```

Comment: I changed the name for the input and the function, or one of either, but the program still doesn't print my name properly. It just shows the input name before the word "function" followed by a bunch of a numbers

Comment: Wait, that's not how I want to fix it.

Comment: The way you changed it only prints the actual name because, you typed "name" in the final print message, which corresponds the "name = input(...)". I want to know how to call the function inside the print message near the end.

Comment: So, what is your requirement?

Comment: Like I want it be like this: print("\nGoodbye", fn())   <---- defined function called inside the print message

Comment: What do you mean by "or one of either"? In your original example, 'name' was first a string then a function. Dipen's example renames only the function named 'name'.

Comment: But when I typed f(n) inside the print message, it just shows the define function a line above the print message I want the function to be in

Comment: @ledwinder96 disregard that comment. I changed it to what he suggested

Comment: And to add on, when I type f(n) inside the print message, it just shows "Goodbye, None"

Comment: I have updated it according to your needs. Please check!

Comment: I tried to but it wouldn't allow me because my reputation is too low

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments to Dipens's answer, I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
print("\nGoodbye %s" % fn())
```

But in that case you don't want fn to actually print anything, only to return a string. In your original example the code would execute along the lines of the following:

```
print("text", print("name"))
```

... which would result in the same/similar behavior as you're experiencing.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was trying to fix it to. Thank you!!! By the way, is there any other way to do it, I find it kind of strange that you used % because I remember one time doing it a different and more simpler way to fix it

Comment: There are plenty of ways to print out variables in python. I suggest reading this: https://realpython.com/python-print/

Comment: Also do you know what the difference between a comma and a plus sign is, when combining two things? I've seen some post talking about it but it seems too much to read at the moment, so could you tell me in brief? I've tried + or , and both work

Comment: Depends on what you're combining and in what context. I'm assuming that you're wondering with regard to print statements? So print("text" + var) will be interpreted as "the string value of var appended to the string 'text'". In the link I suggested above, a comma would result in the same thing but using the default separator for print (which is " "). So in this small example print("text "+var) is the same as print("text",var) - notice the space. But python is smart/tricky in that this condition will not hold for ANY type.